# Object graph and visitor pattern

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to construct an object graph such that:

```
class Root {
    children: IChild[];
}

class BoyChild implements IChild {
    grandChildren: IGrandChild[];
}

class GirlChild implements IChild {
    descendents: IGrandChild[];
}

class MaleGrandChild implements IGrandChild {
}

class FemaleGrandChild implements IGrandChild {
}
```

And then be able to use the visitor pattern to traverse the graph? After adding `BoyChild` and `GirlChild` instances to `Root.children`, I get errors that I cannot add either `MaleGrandChild` or `FemaleGrandChild` to either `grandChildren` array or `descendants` array because neither of the grand children arrays exist on `IChild`.

Comment: Did you try using `extends` instead of `implements`?

Comment: Its because Root.children are in a role of IChild[] and it looks like your `IChild` interface doesn't have grandChildren or descendants. You should correct your interface and make only one property representing descendants instead of having multiple different fields with same purpose on your classes.